# What is the intution behind the matrix inverse formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am learning about matrix inverses and my professor introduced the formula $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=$ $ 1\over(ad-bc)$$\begin{bmatrix}d & -b\\-c & a\end{bmatrix}$ $,if\; and \; only \; if \; ad-bc\neq
0$. Can someone give me some intuition as to why this formula works?

I understand the intuition behind using Gauss-Jordan elimination to find the matrix by applying all of the steps of row reduction to the identity matrix, but this formula seems like magic.

Thank you!

Comment: Just try to multiply it with the original matrix, you will find the identity.

Comment: You may find Gilbert Strang's MIT [lecture on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNpj-gOXW9M) (the first ~19 minutes) illuminating, though it may require watching at least part of the [previous lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23LLB9mNJvc) to get acquainted with determinant properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverse of an invertible matrix is given by
$$A^{-1}={\frac {1}{\det(A)}} \mathrm{adj} (A)$$
Clearly, $\det(A) = ad-bc$ and we can find the adjugate matrix by applying transpose on the cofactor matrix of $A$. This results in the formula
$$A ^{-1} = {\frac {1}{ad-bc}} {\begin{bmatrix}\,\,\,d&\!\!-b\\-c&\,a\\\end{bmatrix}}$$